# select (sum(field) - max(field)) from table group by field

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `prodotti` (
  `ID` smallint(3) NOT NULL,
  `Denominazione` varchar(15) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `prodotti` (`ID`, `Denominazione`) VALUES
(111, 'latte'),
(222, 'uova');


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `fornitori` (
  `ID` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `CF` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `date` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
  `Prezzo` int(3) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `fornitori` (`ID`, `CF`, `date`, `Prezzo`) VALUES
(111, 'AAAAA', '22/11/09', 100),
(222, 'AAAAA', '22/11/09', 200),
(222, 'BBBBB', '28/10/09', 400),
(111, 'CCCCC', '30/12/07', 100),
(222, 'CCCCC', '30/12/07', 200);
```

Now here is some sql query:

```
SELECT P.ID, COUNT(*) 
  FROM prodotti P, 
       (SELECT (SUM(Prezzo) - MAX(Prezzo)) AS T
          FROM Fornitori
        GROUP BY 
               prezzo
        )F
 WHERE F.T <200
GROUP BY 
       P.ID
```

But i have some question,

```
SELECT (
SUM( Prezzo ) - MAX( Prezzo )
) AS T
FROM Fornitori
```

this return `600`, but why add `GROUP BY prezzo`, the result return `100  200  0`? and what is the mean of `WHERE F.T <200` thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you group by `Prezzo`, you'll have one row for every distinct price, aggregated from the rows in `Fornitori`. Then, for each row, the sum of `Prezzo` is computed (which is simply the sum of a single item, since you grouped by `Prezzo`), as is the max, and then those two are subtracted from each other. Without the `GROUP BY`, all rows, and thus, all prices are aggregated and you get the sum of ALL prices minus the maximum of ALL prices.

The question for you is: why are you grouping by `Prezzo` and then using aggregates on it? Usually, you group by one or more columns and then use aggregates on other columns (i.e., not the ones you group by). It seems to me that you probably want to be grouping by something other than `Prezzo`, or, if you do want to group by `Prezzo` (for example, to get information about products of each of the different prices), then you want to be aggregating some other column.

Comment: why the final qeury result is `ID COUNT( * )` `111 2` `222 2`? `SELECT P.ID, COUNT( * ) FROM prodotti P GROUP BY P.` get `ID COUNT( * )` `111 1` `222 1` `what happend add `...WHERE F.T <200
`?

Comment: `F.T` is the result of the expression `SUM(Prezzo) - MAX(Prezzo)`. Notice the alias of that expression (indicated with `AS T`). I'd recommend that you read up on derived tables, aliases and grouping. I think if you come to understand those things, this question will be easier for you.